# Show %s in Access 2010 Crosstab query instead of just counts

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, crosstab

I have the following two queries that build/feed into the third query. My goal is to have a crosstab query of [MCOs] down the left and possible responses/values for [DrpDown] across the top with the values shown as percentages of the total for each [MCO] (so % of row total).

What I have works, but I want to know if I can do it all in one query.

```
    SELECT tblMCOs.MCOs, tblMCOs.DrpDwn, Count(tblMCOs.ID) AS CountOfID
    FROM tblMCOs
    GROUP BY tblMCOs.MCOs, tblMCOs.DrpDwn;

    SELECT tblMCOs.MCOs, Count(tblMCOs.DrpDwn) AS CountOfDrpDwn
    FROM tblMCOs
    GROUP BY tblMCOs.MCOs;

    TRANSFORM Sum(Round([qryMCODrpDwnCt]![CountOfID]/[qryMCOCtDrpDwn]!
    [CountOfDrpDwn],4)*100) AS PCT
    SELECT qryMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs
    FROM qryMCODrpDwnCt INNER JOIN qryMCOCtDrpDwn ON qryMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs = 
    qryMCOCtDrpDwn.MCOs
    GROUP BY qryMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs
    PIVOT qryMCODrpDwnCt.DrpDwn;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I have works, but I want to know if I can do it all in one query.

Crosstab queries can be a bit fussy, but simply inserting the SQL code as subqueries *should* work:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(Round([sqMCODrpDwnCt]![CountOfID]/[sqMCOCtDrpDwn]![CountOfDrpDwn],4)*100) AS PCT
SELECT sqMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs
FROM 
    (
        SELECT tblMCOs.MCOs, tblMCOs.DrpDwn, Count(tblMCOs.ID) AS CountOfID
        FROM tblMCOs
        GROUP BY tblMCOs.MCOs, tblMCOs.DrpDwn
    ) AS sqMCODrpDwnCt
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tblMCOs.MCOs, Count(tblMCOs.DrpDwn) AS CountOfDrpDwn
        FROM tblMCOs
        GROUP BY tblMCOs.MCOs
    ) AS sqMCOCtDrpDwn 
        ON sqMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs = sqMCOCtDrpDwn.MCOs
GROUP BY sqMCODrpDwnCt.MCOs
PIVOT sqMCODrpDwnCt.DrpDwn
```